# my HP Compaq nx6320 WLAN is not responding

Tags: wireless-networking

i reformatted my laptop which is hp compaq nx6320, and of course, everything follows, i installed every driver of laptop needed, but my problem is the wireless part, i have my hp wireless assistant installed and running, but when i turn on my wifi, it doesnt change the status at the hp wireless assistant, its still disabled, as well as the bluetooth, HELP!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem happen to me on the Compaq Presario CQ50-110US I own. Recently I updated the factory installed BIOS to the newest version that was found on the HP web site. After the BIOS update my wireless card was no longer being detected by Windows, and the HP wireless assistant was no longer working or starting.

I searched the internet and and also these HP forums and had trouble finding information on the topic. After digging around for a while I found one post that suggested taking out the battery so that the CMOS would drain and reset the system's devices. The article said that five minutes without the battery would be enough time, but I took out the battery and went to sleep leaving it out overnight.

The next morning I started my laptop without the battery and to my surprise the light went blue, I was able to again open HP Wireless Assistant, and have my internet work again via the wireless card.

Another article I found said that they where able to get the card working again by taking it out of the laptop and then putting it back in place. However, I did not need to do this. Some people have also mentioned that the only way they are able to enable their wireless card is by pressing the button during the boot process (once the "black windows screens" are done and when you see the login screen).

If all else fails, then you could always get a USB wireless device.